# how to store an array into a sub collection in firebase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am learning Firebase and now I want to store my dummy data to Firebase collection,

I have a model class TransactionCategory which has three fields

1. id 2. name 3. array of transactions

like TransactionCategory(id:'1',name:'Shopping',transactions:[])

here I want to make a collection "Transaction Category" and instead of storing transactions in a field I want it to store inside a child collection named 'Transactions'

hope I am clear in explaining what I want...

Parent Collection : TransactionCategory and it has two field(id,name) and a child collection(transactions)

```
List<TransactionCategory> transactionCategoryList = [
  TransactionCategory(id: '1', name: 'Food',
      //this array should be store in child collection
      transactions: [
    Transaction(id: '1', title: 'Dinner', amount: 100),
    Transaction(id: '2', title: 'Breakfast', amount: 30),
    Transaction(id: '3', title: 'Dinner', amount: 230),
  ]),
  TransactionCategory(id: '2', name: 'General',
      //this array should be store in child collection
      transactions: [
    Transaction(id: '1', title: 'Milk', amount: 50),
    Transaction(id: '3', title: 'Detergent', amount: 299),
  ]),
  TransactionCategory(id: '3', name: 'Shopping', transactions:
  //this array should be store in child collection
  [
    Transaction(id: '1', title: 'Clothe', amount: 3000),
    Transaction(id: '2', title: 'Shoes', amount: 1200),
    Transaction(id: '3', title: 'Shoes', amount: 2200),
  ]),
];
```

```
Button(
  title: 'save Categories',
  onPressed: () async {
    //for saving transaction list into a child collection
    final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    
    //here i dont know what should i code
  },
),
```

I want to save dummy data like this format shown in image

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to clean up your question to be clearer on: what you want to do, what you are doing, what you have tried, what specifically needs a clear answer. That would help a lot.

Comment: So isn't that what you already have? I see the `Transactions` is indeed a sub-collection of a document. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @Alex Mamo ,I want as per given image....dummy data should b saved as in given image

Answer (score 1):

According to your last comment, if you want to add a new document inside the "Transactions" sub-collection, then you have to create a reference that points to the sub-collection:

```
CollectionReference transactionsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("TransactionCategories")
    .doc("1")
    .collection("Transactions");
```

Now you can use this collection reference to add documents.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new document inside the "TransactionCategory" sub-collection, then refer to this code

```
final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;    
final CollectionReference _Collection =
        _firestore.collection('TransactionCategories/' + docId + "/Transactions");

DocumentReference documentReferencer = _Collection.doc();

Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{
  "Id": "1",
  "Name": "Food"
};

var result = await documentReferencer.set(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have trid this and work as you want but there must be better short code for it...

```
final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
                          
                          for (var cat in transactionCategoryList) {
                            await _db
                                .collection('TransactionCategories')
                                .doc(cat.id)
                                .set({
                              'Id': cat.id,
                              'Name': cat.name,
                            });
//this is for your array field value to store in sub collection
                            for (var trans in cat.transactions) {
                              await _db
                                  .collection('TransactionCategories')
                                  .doc(cat.id)
                                  .collection('Transactions')
                                  .doc(trans.id)
                                  .set(trans.toJson());
                            }
                          }
                          
                        },
```